# How to download using command line tools with a secondary (backup) source?

Tags: command-line, download, mirror

I use `wget`, `rsync` and `curl` to download files regularly (via https or ssh). One issue when I travel is that servers that are fast to access in one region become slow (or even inaccessible) in another. My current strategy is to use mirrors and switch to mirrors that are local to each region.

I was wondering if there are Unix commandline tools that allow downloading a file from multiple mirrors as the source. The mirrors do not have to be used in parallel. They are used as backups, and the fastest one is used if the connection is lost.

The command line should look like:

```
xxget url1 url2
```

-- Update --

As pointed out by the accepted answer, the aria2c documentation has an example that does exactly  this:

```
Download from 2 sources:

$ aria2c http://a/f.iso ftp://b/f.iso
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [aria2c](https://aria2.github.io/) client has that functionality out of the box. It's a rather slim client and widely available.

It does download in parallel by default, but that will only work to your advantage: if the fastest server is done delivering its part, it'll grab parts that a slower server hasn't yet